# Track how many of our visitors that use a CDN?

Tags: jquery, performance, http, cdn, google-cdn

So there's a lot of hype that you should use a CDN to improve performance, but I don't agree that this is a silver bullet for all cases - eg implement CDNs an all is well...

Our website, for instance, is based in Sweden. We currently use this URL for our jQuery needs: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js

I'm thinking of concatenate the jQuery script with the rest of our scripts to remove one HTTP request and get complete control over the delivery. I don't like dependencies on the uptime of external resources, even if Googles is slightly better then ours.

But I'm not sure - I would likt to measure how many actually use this CDN. Because there's a lot of different CDNs for hosting jQuery, which one is the most popular among my visitors?

Any ideas would be appreciated!

/J

Comment: You can't know what your visitors use, as it is the websites they visite that decide where they get their resources from.

But if you get jquery from googles CDN, then by definition all your users load the script from googles CDN.

Comment: Are you suggesting that you have a pool of possible resources? If you provide only one option then 100% of the traffic from your site goes through that resource.

Comment: you can do so only if you have the access of all CDNs to track the access.

Comment: You can try [Google Analytic][1] or [Open Tracker][2]


  [1]: http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/how-to-track-social-media-traffic-with-google-analytics/
  [2]: http://www.opentracker.net/products/web-analytics/feature/track-unique-visitors

Comment: @AndréSnedeHansen  - That's my point. You just slam a CDN on there, hoping that they visited another site that used the same CDN and version of library as you do AND that the file is still in cache.... There's a lot of if and when and buts right there...

Comment: @doveyg - No, I'm posting a question how I can NOW that a particular CDN actually can help the performance of my website.

Comment: @BhupendraShukla - No, you can't measure that using any analytics tool....

Comment: Who down voted and why?

Comment: In that case I would refer to statistics provided by the CDNs, if they provide such a thing, and compare them to find out which is faster/more widely accessed. The question should not be "Who down voted my question and why?" rather "Why was my question down voted?".

Comment: @doveyg And that would help how? The CDNs hardly keep track of what visitors I have to my page... As the question states - "which one is the most popular among my visitors?". Please keep the answers limited to the topic of the posted question...

Comment: As everyone else has stated, you can't.

Comment: @doveyg - Everyone? I count two.